# TextTrimming on TextBlock while Text bound by DynamicResource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textblock, texttrimming

there is a Problem in my TextBlock.
I have a Resource in a ResourceDictionary of type String and this is bound to an TextBlock via DynamicResource.

On my TextBlock there is TextTrimming active, but on this "Binding" the TextTrimming is not working.

Is this a bug in the framework or i am doing it wrong?

Here's my sample:

```
   <Grid Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="60" >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<TextBlock Text="{DynamicResource PART_HeaderString}" VerticalAlignment="Center"  TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Grid.Column="1"/>
                </Grid>
```

and my String in the resource:

```
<sys:String x:Key="PART_HeaderString">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</sys:String>
```

There are many ways to get this working, but I want to know why this isn't working right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to constraint Grid width for `TextTrimming` to be applied. **TextBlock is place in second column whose width is set to `Auto`** so it will expand till actual width of control i.e. TextBlock in your case.

Instead set some hardcoded width for second column say `50` or set it to `*`. So that all 3 columns share same width.

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
   <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/> <-- HERE
   <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

You will see TextTrimming gets applied now.

Comment: I've tried your solution and it's working fine. Thanks! 
I thought that "Auto" means that the size is limited to Grid.Width.
A working solution was to set colum 1 and 3 to Auto and the second to star value.

Comment: Great.!! Please accept this as an answer if it resolves your query.!! Welcome to SO. Here's a link to help you out. [How to accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).